# Android, call finish() through Handler.post function

Tags: android, multithreading, android-activity, handler

I have Activity A and B
Now I have some "event" that gets processed in another thread.
If triggered the app should start B but then destroy A.

In the thread Ive an handler to post stuff to the UI thread.

```
Handler hexample = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
```

Now, switching is no problem but calling the finish() method is:

```
hexample.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),LobbyActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
    ((Activity)getApplicationContext()).finish();
    }
});
```

This doesnt work as my class cant be cast to android.app.Activity
How do I make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just finish() is enough, no need to cast. You cannot call finish of another Activity in that situation.Your scenario works only if you in Activity A and want to start B, then start B and finish A.

Comment: Do not refer ApplicationContext in intent. give a resonable Context such LocateActivity.class, if you are not working in activity or service, pass Context from Activity when you contruct this class

Comment: im working from application level so I now pass the current activity. thanks for the help!